# Remove Image from .xls File With NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Using C# and NPOI, I want to clear some cells in my .xls file and also remove floating image (i know it is not a part of any cell). I can clear cells by:

```
ICellStyle style = hssfWorkbook.CreateCellStyle();
cell.SetCellValue("");
cell.SetCellFormula("");
cell.CellStyle = style;
```

But, how to remove picture?